# Where to store config passwords

Tags: magento2, database, module, magento-1, configuration

I want to have a custom database connection with a module I am creating.  I am following this tutorial which will work well:

http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/create-external-database-connection/

But my issue is that I dont want to store the database credentials within the module.

What would be the accepted way to securely do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always store connection credentials in the same location that Magento stores their credentials: in the `app/etc/` folder. Magento creates custom xml files such as `local.xml` and `enterprise.xml` - all of which may contain sensitive credentials.

My advice - create your own custom XML file which holds these credentials and load it with your module. Don't forget to provide a default/sample version of the XML config file to deploy with your module so that it has placeholder data that end-users will be filling in.